# Making Perl apps portable. Build a shell script or use Puppet

Tags: perl, configuration, perl-module, puppet

I have a perl app that I maintain locally that needs to be regularly zipped up and sent over to another server that's locked down pretty tightly. The goal is to insure that the sysadmins have to install as few perl mods as possible. Our solution is to make everything work against local::lib.

I have seen some stuff possible with Puppet that, on the surface appears to completely handle this. I am not an expert with Puppet, I only know the basic idea. Before I start embarking on a big Puppet learning adventure, I thought I'd see if anyone here had any suggestions as to the best way to deploy perl apps that depend on local::lib (I'm trying to keep a definable question). That is to say deploying completely self contained perl apps.

Many thanks for any light,
Janie

**Edit:** I stumbled across this as well (for purposes of discussion).

[How do manage your Perl application development, build, and deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655986/how-do-manage-your-perl-application-development-build-and-deployment)

Comment: You may also want to look into [PAR](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PAR) and [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/PAR::Packer) and [App::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/App::Packer) in general.

Comment: Also, if there are "the sysadmins" then it'll be up to them if they want to use Puppet or not. You may want to listen to [FLOSS Weekly ep. 93](http://twit.tv/show/floss-weekly/93) to get a good understanding of what Puppet is and is used for (in an hour or so).

Comment: Thanks derobert. Our sysadmins have no problem using Puppet for sure. They just want to set up something once and forget it. Thanks again for your help. Janie

Comment: Well, that'd not be how one normally uses Puppet. Normally, it'd be *we have too many servers to manage one-by-one by hand anymore, so we're automating server management with Puppet*. You wouldn't generally set it up and forget it—you'd use it routinely for administrative tasks on your servers. So I think you're looking for one of the other solutions.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks derobert! This is a lot of great stuff and I think it answers my question. JW

Comment: I'm working in a similar environment myself.  My solution is to ensure all the modules I need (except for standard modules I'm guaranteed are available on the server) are pure perl.  Then deployment is just a case of unzipping my .tbz in the right location.  My app lives in /srv/[myapp] and the start of @INC is /srv/[myapp]/mod and /srv/[myapp]/lib.  (I realise it's often not practical to live in a pure perl world.)

Comment: The sysadmin site is [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com). This doesn't seem to be that off-topic though.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I always walk away from S.O. smarter than when I showed up. derobert, niczero and Brad Gilbert: thanks for helping me out. JW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - puppet or chef is a solution that I would look to for deploying Perl apps.

You might find David Golden's work on [Pantry](http://search.cpan.org/~dagolden/Pantry-0.009/lib/Pantry.pm) of interest, which is some perl-ish ways of using Chef. He did a [presentation back in July](http://www.slideshare.net/dagolden/cooking-perlwithchefpresentationfinal) that gives a nice overview.

Comment: Better late than never that the answer shows up. I know that there have been so many people who have said it's "overkill" but frankly as long as it works, I'm not entirely sure why it's overkill. Just because you can setup 1000 servers with puppet doesn't mean that you can't set up just one. Answer karma for you adrianh.